# How to create Bond or Pairing in BLE using RxAndroidBLE

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy, rxandroidble

I want to implement **passkey** for connect device or establish the connection with BLE device. I have **6 byte passkey**, So how we will create bond or pairing and send passkey to the BLE device using  RxAndroid library.

Can any one give me reference or document link or demo link for **implementation of Passkey or create bond or pairing while establish connection**.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Hi if i'll share the code in java will that do.

Comment: @Udit Kapahi , Please Can you provide link ?

Comment: I dont have the link I had to write it as an answer... So could you please tell me what exactly do u need here

Comment: Where did ur research ended up till now?

Comment: I am trying to create bond while establish connection. Can you give me idea of function or observer or class name I will do that

Answer (score 3):

First you need to find the nearby devices.

```
public void registerDeviceForAnyNEwDeviceFound() {
    // Register for broadcasts when a device is discovered.
    mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    registerReceiver(mSearchReceiver, filter);
    Log.e("STATUS", "" +
            mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering());
    isSearchReceiverRegistered = true;
}

// Create a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND.
private final BroadcastReceiver mSearchReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.e("SEARCH STARTED", "TRUE");
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            // Discovery has found a device. Get the BluetoothDevice
            // object and its info from the Intent.
            try {
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                String deviceName = device.getName();
                String deviceHardwareAddress = device.getAddress(); // MAC address
                Device mDevice = new Device();
                mDevice.setDeviceName(deviceName);
                mDevice.setDeviceAddress(deviceHardwareAddress);
                mDevice.setmBluetoothDevice(device);

                Log.e("Discovered DEVICE", deviceName);
                Log.e("BOND STATE", "" + device.getBondState());

                nearbyDeviceList.add(mDevice);
                mNearbyDeviceRecAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("EXCEPTION", e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }

        }
    }
};
```

Then you need to register another BroadCastReceiver, this receiver will listen to the bond changes with the device with whom you are going to pair with.

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED);
            registerReceiver(mPairingReceiver, filter);

 private final BroadcastReceiver mPairingReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();

        if (action.equals(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED)) {
            BluetoothDevice mDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            //3 cases:
            //case1: bonded already
            if (mDevice.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                Log.d(TAG, "BroadcastReceiver: BOND_BONDED.");
                Log.e(TAG, "BroadcastReceiver: BOND_BONDED." + mDevice.getName());
                mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

            }
            //case2: creating a bone
            if (mDevice.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDING) {
                Log.d(TAG, "BroadcastReceiver: BOND_BONDING.");
                Log.e(TAG, "BroadcastReceiver: BOND_BONDING." + mDevice.getName());
            }
            //case3: breaking a bond
            if (mDevice.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE) {
                Log.d(TAG, "BroadcastReceiver: BOND_NONE.");
                Log.e(TAG, "BroadcastReceiver: BOND_NONE." + mDevice.getName());
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Finally when you want to pair with the device call:

```
mNearbyDeviceRecAdapter.getItemAtPosition(position).getmBluetoothDevice().createBond();
```

Once you call this statement, this will initiate pairing with the device.

Hope! this helps.

Comment: Please upvote this answer and don't forget to accept it , if this works for you